# Isotope and Bootstrap fluid grid

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grid

I need to build portfolio with thumbnails. Images have to be put on **full width** screen and their number has to change depending on width of the screen (**responsive**). That is why I used **Bootstrap 3** and its **grid system**.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6  item  itemShow">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/400/abstract/1" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6  item  itemShow">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/400/abstract/2" alt="" />
        </div>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

But after page load sometimes I have unexpected problem because second line with images goes up (most ofter in Chrome)

[image]

or while changing window size margins are added to the items

[image]

---

JavaScript code looks like this:

```
$('#isotopeContainer').isotope({
   itemSelector: '.item',
   filter: '.itemShow'
});
```

---

Effect can be found here: http://templates.silversite.pl/test/

Answer (score 1):

See the docs [How do I fix overlapping item elements?](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/beta/faq.html#overlapping)

> If your layout has images, you probably need to use [imagesLoaded](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/beta/appendix.html#imagesloaded).

I would also recommend initializing Isotope within `$(document).ready()`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#isotopeContainer').isotope({
      itemSelector: '.item',
      filter: '.itemShow'
  });
});
```

Comment: Solution with imagesLoaded is helpful for first problem (image from second line on image from first line) but it is not helpful for another problem on Chrome and Firefox. I upgrade JS code in [sample](http://templates.silversite.pl/test/).